# Flutter sending post request returning http error 500

Tags: json, flutter, http

i have been working on flutter project which accepts name and phone number of users but when i save it it shows response 500 but from post man its working fine.
[image]

but from flutter here is the code

```
void RegisterUsers(String names, String phone) async{
  
        String urlInser = "https://hmmmiii.com/api/addUser";
        Map<String, String> headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          //'Accept': 'application/json',

        };
    final msg = jsonEncode({"Name":"$names","PhoneNumber":"$phone"});

    var response = await http.post(urlInser,
        headers: headers,
        body: msg);
    print(response.statusCode);


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('User Registered');
     


    } else {
      print('Unsuccessful');
      

      
    }
```

where names and phone are textController values thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in postman, you are sending the request as form-data, but in your code, you are sending it as a simple JSON.

you have to use `MultipartRequest` instead.

```dart
final url = 'your url';
final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url))
      ..fields['Name'] = 'some name'
      ..fields['PhoneNumber'] = 'some phonenumber';

final response = await request.send();
final responseBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();
print('RESPONSE BODY:   $responseBody');
```